# Identify board game on 4x4 board with 8 black and 8 white pieces

Tags: identify-this-game

Staying in an old farmhouse in France we have found this game.
[image: unknown game image 1]
[image: unknown game image 2]
There is a 4x4 board with 8 black and 8 white pieces. Does anyone know what this game is called and more importantly how to play it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That looks like a set of [Quarto](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto_(board_game)) to me. There are eight dark/eight light pieces, eight tall/eight short pieces, eight round/eight square pieces and eight pointed/eight flat pieces. Usually the fourth attribute is hollow/solid, but the game works in exactly the same way with pointed/flat.

To play the game start with all the pieces off the board, and the first player chooses a piece for the second to place. After it's placed, the second player chooses a piece for the first player to place. Play alternates in this way until a player places a piece that creates a set of four in a straight line that all share a characteristic (e.g. four round pieces in a row). The first player to make four in a row wins.

Comment: Note that the color of the piece doesn't correspond to a player as you might instinctually think.  Both players choose from a common pool and color is just one of the characteristics.

Comment: It's also a delightfully fun game. It's very quick to play, and you can go through quite a few rounds in an evening.

Comment: I'm presuming this is a custom or limited edition version. Probably custom. It's really really sweet looking.

Answer (score 2):

The game is called [**Gobblet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobblet) ([rules PDF](http://www.boardspace.net/gobblet/english/gobblet_rules.pdf)).

Players (2 only) alternate placing (and then shifting already placed) pieces on the board attempting to be first align 4 *gobblets* (ie pieces) in a row,  either horizontally ,vertically, or diagonally.

Players start with only the 3 largest pieces each, and larger pieces can *gobble-up* smaller ones (of either the opponent or it's own colour).

Comment: I have never heard of Gobblet, but after viewing some pictures and reading about how it is played, I am beginning to think that Quarto is a derivative work and that maybe both games could be played with the same set of pieces.

Comment: Gobblet requires pieces which nest in order to work.  The pieces in the photo don't nest.  I have copies of both Gobblet and Quarto, and while they're both attractive wooden-pieced games they most definitely don't use the same pieces.

Comment: @Argyle Thanks for that piece of info, it was not obvious to tell them apart visually. After reading your comment I saw [this](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/GAMES/Goblet/GobletPhoto.jpg), which helped.