# Does anyone know the name of this game?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: A 4x4 board of circle with pieces (cylinders) in two sizes and colors, two big and three small per color, in some of the circles]

Does anyone know this game? Need help!

Comment: Do you have any more information that might help?  How do you know it's a game and not art/ornamental?  How did you get it?  Do you know how old it is? (if you knew you played it in early 1980s for example that can help someone narrow it down). What are the pieces made of?  The picture looks the pieces could be home made rather than a commercially available game

Comment: Is it https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto_(board_game)? In that case, the question is a duplicate of https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18621/identify-board-game-on-4x4-board-with-8-black-and-8-white-pieces

Comment: @ToonKrijthe : no, it isn't quarto. The pieces are all cylinders (no rectangular solids), and none of them are notched.

Comment: @Deo's answer appears to be correct (assuming the pieces will nest), with a home-made version.  Unfortunately the Questioner hasn't looked here since asking the question.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like [Gobblet](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2266/gobblet). Check if the pieces fit into one another?